# How to choose the system keyboard as the only type of input keyboard of a textField?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a text field in the view and I only want the system keyboard to be presented when the user enters text in the textfield. And the user may not switch the keyboard to custom ones. [image: Current view where the user can switch keyboard to other keyboards downloaded from the app store for example]How can I achieve this?

[image: An app from app store where there is no the globe icon in the keyboard to switch the keyboard]

Comment: @rmaddy To simply make the scene cleaner... and it is mainly because I have downloaded another app that is actually able to do this and I feel curious about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in AppDelegate.swift file

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplicationExtensionPointIdentifier) -> Bool {
    if (extensionPointIdentifier == .keyboard) {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know this one. But this only prevents 3rd party keyboards from being used in the app. It doesn't prevent the user from switching to other system keyboards.